# Pscx.IO.PscxPathInfo

Tags: powershell, pscx

I was trying to create a shortcut using new-shortcut from Pscx. But putting in paths I'm always getting that PscxPathInfo error ( string cannot be converted to PscxPathinfo). I already tried $dest = "...path" - and used "get-item $dest" - but nothing helps.
Can someone show me an example how to use new-shortcut?

Kind Regards
Franz-Georg

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug that I think Oisin has fixed in daily bits e.g. this works for me:

```
New-Shortcut C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Reflector.lnk C:\Bin\Reflector.exe
```

We need to get an official release out here shortly.  We fixed quite a few bugs since the original PSCX 2.0 release.

Comment: Yeah, it's a known bug that was actually caused by an engine bug in powershell itself. I've worked around it in the latest checkins.